# Mechanically strong way to connect wires T-junction way

Tags: connector, soldering, mechanical

I have an existing LED light curtain but I would like to redo it in more robust way. It has a main cable with 6 branches hanging down like this:

```
Battery&DC-DC___________________
                |  |  |  |  |  |
                o  o  o  o  o  o
                o  o  o  o  o  o
                o  o  o  o  o  o
                o  o  o  o  o  o
```

At the moment the T-branches are just twisted and soldered around the main but soldering tends to break because branches are flexing a lot.

Are there some recommended T-connectors available? It can be permanent or detachable.

Edit: The wire gauge is not fixed, I think at the moment it uses 0.75 mm²

Comment: What gauge wire?

Comment: You could physically stiffen the electrical connection, so the flexing will take place at an intact part of the hanging cables.

Answer (score 3):

Something like a [3M Scotchlok T-Tap connector](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/Marine/Home/Products/Catalog/?PC_7_RJH9U5230GE3E02LECIE20S4K7000000_nid=GS3MTHGQSCbeVB2NDGZBTHgl) might be what you want.

Be sure to use stranded wire if your application requires flex, it will impart less stress to connections (soldered or not).

[image: t-tap connector]

Comment: Looks very neat